# eval SyntaxError: invalid syntax in python

Tags: python

I want to assign :

```
x0='123'    
x1='123'    
x2='123'    
x3='123'    
x4='123'    
x5='123'    
x6='123'    
x7='123'    
x8='123'    
x9='123'
```

I write the code to express that i can get the output of a string `123` when  input `x1` or `x8` .

```
for i in range(0,10):
    eval("x"+str(i)+"='123'")

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
File "<string>", line 1
  x0='123'
  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How i can do that way?

---

<sub>[**Do not ever use `eval` (or `exec`) on data that could possibly come from outside the program in any form. It is a critical security risk. You allow the author of the data to run arbitrary code on your computer.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) If you are here because you want to create multiple variables in your Python program following a pattern, **you almost certainly have an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info)**. Do not create those variables at all - instead, [use a list or dict appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164).</sub>

Comment: Obligatory link: [Keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html). Don't use `eval` to create variables. Use a list or dictionary instead.

Comment: `eval()` only allows for *expressions*. Assignment is not an expression but a statement.

Comment: Use `exec` for statements not `eval`, as Martijn said use a list/dictionary.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

For dynamic execution of statements use the `exec` function:

```
>>> exec('y = 3')
>>> y
3
```

`eval` usage: `eval(expression)`.

The `expression` argument is parsed and evaluated as a Python expression.

e.g.:

```
>>> s = 3
>>> eval('s == 3')
True
>>> eval('s + 1')
4
>>> eval('s')
3
>>> eval('str(s) + "test"')
'3test'
```

Answer (score 26):

`eval()` only allows for *expressions*. Assignment is not an expression but a statement; you'd have to use `exec` instead.

Even then you could use the `globals()` dictionary to add names to the global namespace and you'd not need to use any arbitrary expression execution.

You **really** don't want to do this, you need to [keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html) and use a list or dictionary instead:

```
x = ['123'] * 10
```

would give you a list you can address as `x[0]`, `x[1]`, etc. without having to execute arbitrary expressions.

Answer (score -3):

You can you this expression.

```
eval('"x"+str(i)+"="+"123"')
```