# Plain-text, Python-syntax file to save and restore some class variables?

Tags: python

In my case, I'd like to save and restore some "plain" variables (i.e., ints, strings) in a file, which would end up as class properties. This example is the closest I got, by using `import`:

**`a.py`**

```
b = 134
a = "hello"
```

**`mytest.py`**

```
import inspect

class Teost:
  from a import *
  def __init__(self):
    self.c = 12
    print(inspect.getmembers(self)) # has a and b
    print(self.__dict__)            # no a and b
    print(self.a)                   # prints "hello"

xx = Teost()
```

So, here `a.py` acts as the file storing the variable values (`a` and `b`), and `from a import *` inside the class gets them as class properties (`self.a` and `self.b`), which is pretty much what I want.

Unfortunately, turns out using starred `import` syntax in a class is frowned upon:

```
$ python mytest.py
mytest.py:3: SyntaxWarning: import * only allowed at module level
  class Teost:
[('__doc__', None), ('__init__', <bound method Teost.__init__ of <__main__.Teost instance at 0x7fdca368ab90>>), ('__module__', '__main__'), ('a', 'hello'), ('b', 134), ('c', 12)]
{'c': 12}
hello
```

... so I get an ugly "SyntaxWarning: import * only allowed at module level", which I cannot get rid of (unless I disable warnings, which I don't want to do)

So, do I have any other options, to use a file written as `a.py` (i.e. in plain-text, Python syntax), and have the variables in it end up as some classes properties?

(I've seen [How do I save and restore multiple variables in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568007/how-do-i-save-and-restore-multiple-variables-in-python), but I'm not interested in `pickle` or `shelve` because neither of them writes in a Python-syntax, plain-text file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the module into your class like:

**Code:**

```
class Teost:
    import a as _a_py_attrs

    def __init__(self):
        for name in dir(Teost._a_py_attrs):
            if not name.startswith('__'):
                setattr(self, name, getattr(Teost._a_py_attrs, name))
```

**Test Code:**

```
xx = Teost()
print(xx.__dict__)
print(xx.a)
```

**Results:**

```
{'a': 'hello', 'b': 134}
hello
```

**As Class Attributes:**

If it would be preferable to have these as class attributes, instead of instance attributes, you can do:

```
class Teost:
    """ My Test Class """

import a as _a_py_attrs
for name in dir(_a_py_attrs):
    if not name.startswith('__'):
        setattr(Teost, name, getattr(_a_py_attrs, name))
```

**Test Code:**

```
xx = Teost()
print(xx.__dict__)
print(xx.a)
```

**Results:**

```
{}
hello
```

Comment: Thanks @StephenRauch - I think I like this approach best, cheers!

Comment: Wait, but `setattr(self, name, ....)` will set `name` as an *instance* attribute, not a class attribute... You could do this in a metaclass though. Or use `setattr(Teost, name,  ...)` to set to a class attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I mean, you could do something super hacky:

```
import inspect
import a

class A:
  def __init__(self):
    self.c = 12
    print(('a', 'hello')  in inspect.getmembers(self)) # has a and b
    print(('b', 134) in inspect.getmembers(self))
    print('a' in self.__dict__)            # no a and b
    print('b' in self.__dict__)
    print(self.a)                   # prints "hello"

for name in dir(a):
    if not name.startswith('__'): # very brittle here
        val = vars(a)[name]
        setattr(A, name, val)

x = A()
```

You would probably want to wrap the above logic in a metaclass.

Maybe just using `exec` is cleaner. It shouldn't be too big of a problem if you trust the source of `a.py`.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga - good to have this approach in mind, too; cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Well, found a workaround (which doesn't raise errors or warnings) - instead of `import`, read the file and then `exec` (not `eval`, [eval SyntaxError: invalid syntax in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558548/eval-syntaxerror-invalid-syntax-in-python)) it:

```
  #from a import *
  with open('a.py') as x: fstr = x.read()
  exec(fstr)
```

... although I should probably feel uncomfortable for using `exec`...