# SyntaxError: print doesn't work in eval()

Tags: python, printing, syntax-error, eval

**Code:**

```
eval("print('foobar')")
```

**Output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled.py", line 30, in <module>
    eval("print('foobar')")
  File "<string>", line 1
    print('foobar')
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What your python version?

Comment: Given that it throws a `SyntaxError` it's python-2.x. You need `exec` for statements like `print` in python 2.

Comment: w.r.t. the duplicate: I'm voting to leave this open. The potential duplicate does not mention `print` specifically, so in terms of internet search queries leaving the current question open would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the exec function. Like this:

```
exec("print('foobar')")
```

See [What is the difference between an expression and a statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728073/what-is-the-difference-between-an-expression-and-a-statement-in-python)
for more informations.

Answer (score 2):

`print` is an operator in Python 2, and a function in Python 3. Which version do you use?

Comment: ^ This is essentially the correct answer. `eval` works on expressions only. In Python 3, `print` is a function, and so its use is a valid expression. In Python 2, its use is a statement, not an expression, so it won't evaluate. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558548/eval-syntaxerror-invalid-syntax-in-python for more info

Comment: If you remove the "which version do you use" part and say that's the reason why it fails on python-2.x it would be an even better answer.

Comment: Using Python 2 so I want exec() then? Makes a lot of sense, thanks

Comment: @IbraheemRodrigues You don't want to use `exec` or `eval` - trust me! But if you have to use them, then you need `exec` for `print` in python 2.

Comment: I would use "statement" instead of "operator". https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print

Comment: @MSeifert In terms of security (code injection)? I am using it to make a [brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

`eval` evaluates expressions, not statements, so you need to pass it the `print` *function*, not the `print` *statement*. By default, `print` is a statement in Python 2, and the `print` statement doesn't exist in Python 3. However, the `print` function *is* available in recent versions of Python 2 via a `__future__` import. The `print` function is actually defined in those versions of Python 2 but it's masked by the `print` statement; the import makes the `print` statement unavailable, thus exposing the `print` function.

Demo, tested on Python 2.6.6:

```
from __future__ import print_function

eval("print('foobar')")
```

**output**

```
foobar
```

---

BTW, it's generally *not* a good idea to use `eval` or `exec`, unless you have no alternative. They are relatively slow, and have security risks if you pass them unsanitized strings to evaluate / execute. For details, please see [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) by SO veteran Ned Batchelder. To evaluate simple Python literals you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).